# How to Resolve Duplicate Query String Generated Urls

Tags: product-urls, duplicate

My website generated Query string generated urls and just because of it google penalize my website.Please let me know how to resolve that duplicate url issue.

http://www.ritukumar.com/lehenga/bridal

after query string :

http://www.ritukumar.com/lehenga/bridal?mode=list

Please let me know the best possible way to resolve that issue

Comment: Maybe this link might help : http://inchoo.net/online-marketing/magento-seo-how-to-handle-problems-caused-by-layered-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned about this, Log into G webmasters, click your site with these url's, go to Crawl / URL Parameters, Add Parameter, set ? to "Sorts", "Let Google Bot" Decide.

I doubt very seriously if Google penalized your site for this. Almost all sites have queries added to url's. Google usually ignores them, unless it's the only way to crawl a page. Make sure you have your canonical's set for category and product. Google will be able to tell which page is preferred, and ignore the rest.